# Debugging not breaking in visual studio 2012 cakephp project

Tags: php, cakephp, visual-studio-2012, xdebug, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using the PHP Tools for visual studio 2012 and I am trying to get the debugging to work.

My project is a cakephp project.

I have tried setting my project properties to use a start url. I made a test page and put it in my webroot folder and the debugging worked.

But when I put breakpoints in one of my controllers or views the breakpoint doesn't get hit when navigating to one of the pages.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: You say you've put the page inside the webroot? The pages are not inside your view directories?

Comment: @thaJeztah I put a test page in the webroot. The test page worked. The files in my view directories are not working.

Comment: With not working, you mean: the break points, or not working at all?

Comment: @thaJeztah By not working I mean visual studios is not stopping at the breakpoints. The pages are loading in my browser.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Your question was a bit confusing because of that. Unfortunately I don't think I can help you out with the VS part, I use PhpStorm myself, don't have experience with VS for PHP development. Maybe somebody else will be able to help you out with the additional information.

Comment: perhaps you could use the Visual Studio support forums--and add the answer back here :), they're really fast in replying http://support.devsense.com/viewforum.php?f=21